# Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to grab the first user from a **SQL** database using `Entity model` that is talking to a already existing database that has a *userID* of the user I am looking for. This and a second error appear.

> Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type
>   `System.Func<iomnientitylibrary.user,bool>` because some of the
>   **return** types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate **return** type.

Cannot implicitly convert type `int` to `bool`.

```
public user GetUser(int userID)
{
     using (var context = new iomniEntities())
    {
        user u = context.users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.userID);

        return u;
    }
}
```

`context.users.ToList()` is working properly but I don't want to be **that inefficient**.

Comment: There is no need for `ToList` here (that will not change the types required for subsequent Enumerable calls). This error is a *compile-time type-error*. Look at the expression/line with the "red squiggles". In particular, `user => user.userID` does *not* return a boolean value which is what the error is trying to say. (Not using ToList in certain EF scenarios is may lead to *runtime errors*, which are different than *compile-time type-errors*: it would not fix this issue.)

Answer (score 7):

When using the expression:`user u = context.users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.userID);` 
 the return type is of userID ( this is determined by the 2nd part of Lambda expression)  and NOT of type: 'user' , which the statement expects as per the declaration: `user u`

So, if you want to return a single `user`  whose userID is 'userID', use:

```
user u = context.users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.userID==userID);
```

OR you can also use:

```
user u = context.users
         .Where(user => user.UserId==UserID)
         .Select(user => user).Single();
```

Also make sure you have the Using statement: `using System.Linq;`

Comment: .Select(x => x)  is a useless term, always

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have your syntax off a bit. Try:

```
public user GetUser(int intUserID)
{
     using (var context = new iomniEntities())
    {
        user u = context.users.Where(u => u.userID == intUserID).FirstOrDefault();

        return u;
    }
}
```

Or to hold onto your version, it just needs touched up:

```
public user GetUser(int intUserID)
{
     using (var context = new iomniEntities())
    {
        user u = context.users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.userID == intUserID);

        return u;
    }
}
```

Comment: `.Where(f).FirstOrDefault() and .FirstOrDefault(f)` should result in equivalent (the same?) queries. In any case, both forms *are typed the same* so a type-problem (with `f`) affecting one will affect the other.

Comment: @user2246674 Yes. I had missed the `Func<TSource, Boolean>` aspect of both the `.Where()` and `.FirstOrDefault()`...edited.

Answer (score 1):

The expression in your `FirstOrDefault` method isn't right - it wants an expression that returns a `bool` and you give it `user => user.userID` which returns an `int`.

Just rewrite it to account for the parameter you're passing in: `user => user.userID == userID`

That said, if there wouldn't be 2 users with the same ID you're probably better off with `context.Users.SingleOrDefault(user => user.userID == userID)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your *lambda* is wrong, it needs to return a `boolean` and yours just returns the `.userID`.

You need to use some kind of comparison, like:

`user => user.userID == 10`

**FirstOrDefault** returns the first or *default (null in your case)* of the items that match the lambda expression. It does not return the first item in the list which is what I think you are wanting. Without knowing what the context.Users data type is, I can't tell you a better way to do this.

You could use something like:

`user => user != null`

Answer (score 0):

Like others mentioned you need to adjust your code a bit to do the comparison.
Anyway I would do it with Single/SingleOrDefault as your are expecting to get a single user who matches the user id provided.

```
user u = context.users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.userID == userID);
```

or just do the return

```
return context.users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.userID == userID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check properties of class 'user' are declared as public.

like this

```
public class user
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to filter the users based on "UserId" and then select the first one . so the query should be like this :

```
User user = context.Users.Where(x=>x.UserId == UserId).FirstOrDefualt();
```

Comment: All the existing answers say this. What is the added value of your answer?